# How to train Keras Sequential model in batches?

Tags: python, keras, csv, sequential-pattern-mining

newbie here. I have a large dataset in many local CSV files. It's impossible to fit it in memory within budget. How can I train a Sequential model in batches? I've found `batch_size` in `fit` [method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method) and `train_on_batch` [method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#train_on_batch-method), but the difference and use cases are totally unclear to me.

On a small amount of data I'd try:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
      
X = np.loadtxt("input_X_31.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=int)

y = np.loadtxt("input_y_31.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=int)
(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True, train_size=0.7)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
# .. add layers here

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

If I call `model.fit` in a loop providing different `X_train, y_train` from different files - will it work, won't it destroy previous results?

[Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/better-to-learn-the-same-small-set-for-multiple-epochs-then-go-to-the-next-or-le) I've read that I can get better accuracy if I loop over all files with small `epochs` level but many times than loop over all files once but having many epochs for each file. Is there any effective way to do so and not load GBs from the files every time?

What's the most effective way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a custom data generator using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` that loads the data into memory as needed, preventing all data to be in memory at once (see also [the example provided in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)). You can then provide this generator as the `x` argument.